# get coordinates from google Maps using mouse event

Tags: google-maps, c#-4.0, mouseevent

How to get the coordinates of an Google Map using mouse click in the c# and .net?

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand your question.

I found a nice article about getting coordinates from Google Maps using C#:

http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/address-geocoding/

Maybe it will be useful for you.